# UICollectionView Update Animated

Tags: swift, animation, uicollectionview

I got a UICollectionView and a rest api. I fetch my data and save it to arrays with entity objects I created. I've got entity objects which represent a user, a connection between two users and notifications (so the user can grand a connection between users).

I present all my data inside a UICollectionView, which has 3 sections for the users profile, notifications and his connections to other users. Each got an own prototype cell with an own custom class.

When I load my ViewController and start updating the data (fetching from api), I save a hash to track if the data has changed. If it has changed towards the currently displayed data, I save my new data objects to my data model and call a method "updateUI()" at my ViewController.

So far so good, everything works - but I want my CollectionView to do the updates animated.

I searched through the internet and read that the CollectionView has already methods for adding and deleting cells. But in my case I can not track how my data has changed, I only know that it has changed if the hash has changed.

So when I call "reloadData()" in my "updateUI()"-method the whole CollectionView flashes up and the update is pretty ugly.

How can I keep track how my data has changed, or how can I animate the datachange when displayed to the CollectionView in my "updateUI()"-method?

**UPDATE**

To start with some code here is my data handler, which holds all the data for my views:

```
class DataHandler {

  static var connections : [Connection] = []
  static var ownProfile : User?
  static var notifications : [Notification] = []
  static var connectionsHash : String? = nil
  static var ownProfileHash : String? = nil
  static var notificationsHash : String? = nil
  static var overviewHash : String? = nil

  //plus getter and setter for every attribute
}
```

This is how I store my json objects from the api into my datahandler, for example the notifications:

```
var notifications : [Notification] = []
for (_,notification):(String, JSON) in dataObject["notifications"] {
  let notificationObj = Notification(json: notification)
  notifications.append(notificationObj)
}
DataHandler.setNotifications(notifications)
```

And in my View Controller I set up the cells with data from DataHandler:

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,      cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell : UICollectionViewCell!

    let notificationCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("NotificationCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NotificationCell
    let ownProfileCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("OwnProfileCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OwnProfileCell
    let overviewUserCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("OverviewUserCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OverviewUserCell

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
      //setting up cell for notification
      //with data from DataHandler
      cell = notificationCell
    case 1:
      //setting up cell for own profile
      //with data from DataHandler
      cell = ownProfileCell
    case 2:
      //setting up cell for connected user
      //with data from DataHandler
      cell = overviewUserCell
    default: break

    }
    return cell
  }
```

A typical response from my api looks like this:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "notifications": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "lastAlarm": 1460493400,
        "alarmDelay": 0,
        "routine": 20000,
        "master": {
          "email": "*********",
          "id": 12,
          "created": 1454117165,
          "imageUrl": "http://192.168.2.171:9999/profileimages/4.jpg",
          "name": "**********",
          "lastReport": 1460857863
        },
        "active": false
      }
    ],
    "connections": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "slave": {
          "email": "*********",
          "id": 12,
          "created": 1454117165,
          "imageUrl": "http://192.168.2.171:9999/profileimages/4.jpg",
          "name": "**********",
          "lastReport": 1460857863
        },
        "alarmDelay": 20000,
        "lastAlarm": 1460493400,
        "routine": 2000,
        "active": true
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "slave": {
          "email": "********",
          "id": 13,
          "created": 1454957407,
          "imageUrl": "http://192.168.2.171:9999/profileimages/5.jpg",
          "name": "*******",
          "lastReport": 0
        },
        "alarmDelay": 2000,
        "lastAlarm": 1460493400,
        "routine": 200,
        "active": true
      }
    ],
    "profile": {
      "id": 11,
      "shortestInterval": 300,
      "imageUrl": "http://192.168.2.171:9999/profileimages/3.jpg",
      "email": "********",
      "created": 1454117103,
      "name": "******",
      "lastReport": 1461674777
    }
  },
  "hash": "1c402ff86c8a3f9b7c0b2376d736fe47",
  "error": null
}
```

And when I receive data from my api successfully I call the method updateUI in my ViewController:

```
  func updateUI(animated : Bool) {
    self.userCollectionView.reloadData()
  }
```

I also got some animations for cells, but only by first loading:

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if(duration == 0.5) {
      cell.layer.opacity = 0.0
      UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
        cell.layer.opacity = 1.0
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you'll have some trouble getting a concrete answer as it is. Add some code snippets, I think updateUI and how you retrieve your data would be pretty helpful to anyone who reads this.

Comment: And maybe how you populate your collection view with the data, is it in an array? Is the array populated with tuples? It's hard to know how to animate your collection view/change your structure to enable you to animate without this kind of info

Comment: Reload collection view using GCD asyn handler with uiview.animatewithduration it will give u smooth animation rather than flashing

Comment: @OlivierWilkinson Updated my post, sorry!

Comment: No worries, I just didn't want you to get no answers!